# FullCalendar return data of specific Id

Tags: php, jquery, pdo, fullcalendar

What im doing wrong here? I`m trying to select an event by id, here is 1 by default just for testing purposes.

Calendar events POST

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
       var utilizador =1;
       var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable:true,
        header:{
         left:'prev,next today',
         center:'title',
         right:'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        events: 
        {
          url:'../Components/calendar/load.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: function() { 
            return {
                  id: utilizador
                    };
                }
        },
....
```

My Load.php where i try to select the id i got before

```
<?php

//load.php
if(isset($_POST["id"]))
{
$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=novamente', 'root', '');

$data = array();

$query = " 
SELECT * FROM consulta ORDER BY idconsulta WHERE utilizador=:id";

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $row)
{
 $data[] = array(
  'id'   => $row["idconsulta"],
  'title'   => $row["local"],
  'start'   => $row["horainicio"],
  'end'   => $row["horafim"],
  'utilizador'   => $row["utilizador"]
 );
}

echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

I know it will be a minor error but im just learning jquery and php. Thanks!

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the given code? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I'd rather closed it as "caused by a typo" or "needs debugging details". but you know, *reputation hungry participants*. So the faster the better

Comment: you need to fix the $statement->execute(); line, making it as shown in tutorials

Comment: i dont know why it was closed... so im not receiving any data with that id, when in my database i have 2. I can show them all but when i try to show a certain id like that, it doesnt show.

Comment: I still cant managed to get it working, any one knows the solution ?

Comment: Feel free to add more details to your question - start by answering what **exactly** is not working

Comment: i manage to get it working after carefully analysing the solution given to me